# How to click the login button with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

How do I click the `submit` button in this form with selenium?

**HTML**

```
<form name="loginform" method="post" action="https://ap.hongik.ac.kr/login/LoginExec3.php"
  onsubmit="chkFrontLogin();return false;">
  <div class="t">
    <div class="r">
      <div class="c q1">
        <div class="id"><label>id</label><input type="text" name="USER_ID"></div>
        <div class="pw"><label>password</label><input type="password" name="PASSWD"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="c q2">
        <button type="submit" class="button submit"><span class="lbl">login</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" name="Refer" value="http://gw.hongik.ac.kr/index.php">
</form>
```

**My code**

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='main']/div[@class='align']/table/tbody/tr/td/form/button").click()
```

I used xpath and searched stackoverflow.

I cannot find a clue for the error(NosuchElementException).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div/div/div[2]/button/span")
```

An easy way to locate the correct xpath is to right-click and [Inspect] element in Chrome, then right-click the HTML code segment and [Copy] -> [Copy XPath].

Answer (score 2):

Your button has an attribute called 'type' that you can use to find it:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Chrome:**
when you right-click on a button you interest (login, submit etc), you click "Inspect", than you click "copy", and after you choose "copy full xPath".
In my case I received the follows:

> /html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]
> after I put it into the

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]")
elem.click()
```

it worked for me.
If you will choose "copy xPath" instead of "copy full xPath" it also can work. After the "copy xPath" I received

> //*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]

but now I do the following

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/button[1]")
elem.click()
```

and it also work.

**In Firefox** it also works: Inspect->copy->XPath. You can to compare a copied links from Chrome

Comment: Learn about relative XPath and try to construct and use relative XPath expressions rather than using absolute XPath expressions. Absolute XPaths are un-reliable and flaky.